# How do I replace Windows with Ubuntu, yet keep my data?

Tags: system-installation

I need to install Ubuntu instead of Windows 7. Can you tell me the steps to do it? I don't want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Any precautions needed before installing Ubuntu? How do I install Ubuntu 11.10 without losing the current data in my laptop?

Comment: See my answer here [How to Install Ubuntu on Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185860/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-windows/185870#185870)

Comment: How is your hard drive partitioned? Single partition or multiple partitions?

Comment: @Mitch I don't think that's what the OP is looking for. They want to replace Windows entirely, not run Ubuntu within it.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help . I am now using Ubuntu Really awesome . I used it in my PC 1 year back , now installed in laptop instead of built in Windows 7 ..

Comment: [Related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243849/vista-wont-boot-i-dont-have-the-installation-disk-with-me-can-i-install-ubun) (but probably not a duplicate).

Answer (score 2):

Since the process involves a lot of steps, I think it'd be better to provide a link.

So here you have it: [How to Install Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin)

If you've any other queries, don't hesitate to ask.

---

**If you want to retain any data which is stored in C: drive, make a backup either on some other partition or on some external media.**

If you install Ubuntu in the C: Drive (where the windows is installed) everything in the C: will be deleted. (C: contains all the contents of your *Desktop*, *My Documents*, *Recycle Bin*, and in most cases all your installed programs and files related to them).

On the other hand, if you choose any other partition, the contents of that partition would be deleted.

Since you want to remove Windows and install only Ubuntu, you'll have to choose C: while installing Ubuntu. There will be a window like below while installation and there'll be plenty of other options in your case and I guess you'll be able to choose to remove Windows and install Ubuntu.

[image]

If not, you'll have to manually select the partition containing Windows and install Ubuntu on it.

Comment: If i choose whole disk to install , it will cause loss of data right ?? Or can i can choose the C drive in which current OS ( windows 7 ) installed , provided it does not contain any relevant data ?

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: glad it helped! :)

Comment: The link is dead. Too bad you decided to link it instead of pasting the contents of the article in here.

Comment: @Ejaz I think I found that link http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. install Ubuntu alongside Windows,
2. boot Ubuntu,
3. mount the Windows partitions in Ubuntu and
4. remove everything that you don't want to keep, e. g. everything but the `Users` directory.