# Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu, keeping D: drive

Tags: system-installation

I need to replace my windows 10 system with Ubuntu. Not a dual boot as I do not need to keep Windows.

I do not want to lose my D: partition though. Windows is installed on the C: partition.

How can I do that?

Comment: You have to keep Windows or at least a Windows repair CD/flash drive. As your d: drive will need chkdsk & defrag which can only be done using Windows. Or backup, reformat to Linux and restore data.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate as we are looking at a seperate partition rather than a separate drive here. While the called duplicate does have some valid related information, I'm VTR

Comment: This seems like a better choice for a duplicate.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/188116/how-do-i-replace-windows-with-ubuntu-yet-keep-my-data?rq=1

Comment: That or https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 1):

Simply start the Ubuntu installer and when it asks where to install Ubuntu, be sure to choose "Something else". Then click the partition (named WINDOWS in all uppercase for sure) and delete it, then mount it to "/" as ext4 filesystem. Leave the other partition untouched (which is your D partition). The partitions will not be called C and D by the way. After installation the D drive should be accessible and most likely show up as a disk icon in the launcher.

As always I would say as good advice to backup your most important data from your D drive. It will make you feel a lot more comfortable during the installation and it is good to backup important data anyway ;-)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, always take a backup!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would wait a short time and get the latest release 17.04. After loosing lots of data over the years, I would back up your stuff on your D drive, just in case. Then I would get a flash pen with a bootable version of Ubuntu and install it on there, Then I would install the latest version on the system.

Comment: For a new user, it might be better to stick with the LTS releases - i.e. 16.04. Then upgrades only need to be done every two years rather than every six months.

Comment: A very valid point. Personally, I only suggested 17.04 as it would be the latest and greatest and I have not had any issues with the updates.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. And if it's newer hardware, 17.04 might actually support it better. Just wanted to get the suggestion on the record.