# Can I install Ubuntu on the same drive as windows?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Ubuntu on Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185860/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-windows)

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.4.1 on by desktop but on the same drive on which I have already installed windows using windows installer of Ubuntu. So I want to ensure that it won't harm my existing operating system and the associated files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're using the windows installer (WUBI), you need not worry about your Windows installation. Ubuntu will be installed in a virtual drive (a file with all the ubuntu files in it) and it won't harm your Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but make sure you have a seperate partition (at least 5GB size https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements ) on this drive. During installation you will format this partition, so backup important data first!

Comment: He said he's using the windows installer which doesn't need to create a separate partition.