# Where's ubuntu launcher

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu not showing up on boot menu after Wubi installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75314/ubuntu-not-showing-up-on-boot-menu-after-wubi-installation)

I downloaded ubuntu. Restarted my computer. Logged in. And there is my Windows desktop just like always. Did I miss something? I don't know how to get to the launcher that I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (in behalf of @gradi3nt): I need more information before I can help you. What do you mean by downloaded Ubuntu? Did you go to Ubuntu.com, download the disk image and then install ubuntu, or did you just restart after downloading the file?

When you say log in, do you mean that you logged into Windows (blue splash screen that says Windows 7 on the bottom)?

Also, what exactly to do mean by launcher? The ubuntu Unity desktop?

Comment: this should help 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/185860/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment not an answer (Rules don't allow me to comment because I'm not reputable enough, apparently):

I need more information before I can help you. What do you mean by downloaded Ubuntu? Did you go to Ubuntu.com, download the disk image and then *install* ubuntu, or did you just restart after downloading the file?

When you say log in, do you mean that you logged into Windows (blue splash screen that says Windows 7 on the bottom)?

Also, what exactly to do mean by launcher? The ubuntu Unity desktop?

Please add in some details, and then I will try my best to help out more!

Comment: I added your comment